# Data Source for PyEphem?

Tags: pyephem

I am trying to reference the use of PyEphem in my code. Their website shows that data sources are listed below "Documentation", but isn't there anymore. Does anyone know where they take their data from?

Thanks

Comment: By “data sources” the header simply means the link to “Catalogs” further down the page — https://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/catalogs.html — is that the page you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, but that only provides info for asteroids, comets, and satellites, whereas I want to reference coordinates for stars. Sorry if this is supposed to be something simple, but I am very new to this

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! You will want to edit your question, then, so both its title and its body make clear you are asking for star coordinates. Making it as specific as possible will increase its chances of surviving on Stack Overflow.

Comment: (The opening sentence, for example, instead of “I am trying to reference the use of PyEphem in my code” might be “I want to load a star catalog into PyEphem and ask for the coordinates of several stars.” Also: specify whether you need only famous bright stars, or the many dimmer stars behind them.)

Comment: Ah, there may have been some confusion. I have already extracted information about the stars that I need in pyphem. But I am unsure where the data originates from, as I source these in my bibliography, hence why I am looking for the 'data source'. Sorry about that!

Comment: Understood! I suggest, for future readers of this page, revising the question title and text with that clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There were several sources involved in creating PyEphem’s little star catalog, some providing the detailed positions and other supplying the popular names. They are detailed in the `star.py` module’s docstring, which you can view on your own system by running `pydoc ephem.stars` or can view online by looking at the source code on GitHub:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/fc11ddf3f2748db2fa4c8b0d491e169ed3d09bfc/ephem/stars.py#L8

I will also plan to add it to the documentation on the web, so that it’s more easily discoverable.